# What's the range of numbers we can represent with N bits?

Tags: binary, twos-complement

For unsigned integers we can represent numbers ranging from

0 to 2<sup>N</sup> - 1

And for signed integers like two's complement the range is

-2<sup>(N-1)</sup> to 2<sup>(N-1)</sup> - 1

How is the signed range calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the deal. Let's do it for 2 bits, so `N=2`.

We get `Range=-2 to 1`, ie it can represent `-2,-1,0,1`.

Now if `N=4`, we have `Range=-8 to +7`.

I can't understand where are you stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**For unsigned integers :** 
we use all `N` bits to represent numbers ranging from `0 to 2^N - 1` ,its because if we use all N bit positions and calculate different configuration by placing either `0` or `1` in each position, we can get at max integer `2^N - 1` (which is `11...upto N times`) and lowest integer as `0` ( which is `00..upto N times`). And, hence all values from `0` to `2^N - 1` can be represented.

**For Signed integers :**
Here we basically use `N-1` bits to represent integer numbers and `1` bit is exclusively reserved for determining sign of that integer. So, we can represent numbers ranging from `-2^(N-1)` to `2^(N-1) - 1`. The most significant bit as `1` represent the negative integers whereas most significant bit as `0` represent non negative integer values. Here, we can represent negative from `-1` to `-2^(N-1)` from the fact that we may utilize number with all `N` bits as `1`. Basically compilers use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation to represent integers.